# How To Capture All Cell Changes in Online Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have an excel document on sharepoint that is accessed by 50 people which tracks work items. These are complex work items that take an average of a month to complete and involve many different departments. There are different statuses for these work items and I'm trying to find out which of these are the bottlenecks.

I'm sure this can be done with macros, but since this is on sharepoint being used by many and often simultaneously, I'm looking for a solution that will avoid macros.

I can get the most recent status of `A1` by doing the following in `B1`

```
=IF(A1 <> "",CONCAT(A1,CONCAT("-",NOW())),"")
```

but can I concatenate `B1` with itself to capture every status change date?

[image]

Comment: Is that "status" drop down in `A1`? What is you desired outcome? Concatenating a cell with itself using formulas essentially creates an infinite loop. You would need VBA to avoid that problem

Comment: Yes, the status is in A1. My desired out come is to capture the time each time the status is changed. B1 would essentially be a list of times concatenated with the status during the switch. Thank you and I think you may be right regarding the VBA.